# Increasing frequency of Test in Review when about to get badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, review-audits

I was reviewing the Close Votes queue on StackOverflow today morning. And I got 4-5 audit reviews for testing if I am paying attention. This hasn't been so frequent in past. I thought that might be normal.

After completing my 40 reviews of day, I started paying attention to other usual stuff and office work. In some time, I got notification of Silver badge for completing 250 review tasks.

So I wonder, if increased review audits were due to badge progress logic.

Was it just a co-incident or was it actually due to badge?

Comment: Umm.. I don't think so.